# Insert value by Fernet.generate_key() into bytea?

Tags: python, postgresql, fernet

I've tried

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (key BYTEA, key_uuid UUID)
```

Python

```
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO table_name (key, key_uuid) VALUES({Fernet.generate_key()}, uuid_generate_v4())")
```

It gives an error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: "j" is not a valid binary digit
LINE 1: ...me (key, key_uuid) VALUES(b'jBB72dwn...
                                     ^
```

Or am I understanding this wrong..?

Comment: What value do you get in `Fernet.generate_key()`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal crypto key, random byte literal to encode and decode data

Comment: Don't use string interpolation (f-strings) to set values in SQL strings. Pass the value to the `execute` method, it'll properly inject it into the query. See [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: @Marth thanks!
Yeap, I am an idiot :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I used f-strings. Don't use them, yeah...
[Documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Thanks @Marth ♥